# Random file accesses to server's ip

Tags: security, webserver

```
[Sat Jun 22 13:07:06 2013] [error] [client 208.80.194.26] File does not exist: /[removed]/2370604C4AB20069B35E9844BE72140307F553D33124FF9D0C91F136B307F81C1A998310533A1A8526DF06BBE8D5FEB5A0375FE33BFFDE5B237E4C8B95606331082E5E60D709B5DD318F4BDE3374
```

I'm seeing file requests like this every now and again in Apache's log, always with randomized filenames, and notice the odd hack attempt that's blocked by my security.
Should I just block IPs myself, or is there an easier automated way? Cronjob of some sort perhaps? Or is there something else I should be doing?
I can't seem to find anything about this through Google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reality is that these "attacks" are mostly just robots crawling the web looking for a specific webpage, or following links.  If you have a "robots.txt" file and you expect that to stop them, it won't.  If you are trying to reduce the consumption on traffic, then I have some suggestions below.  If you only care about having your website accessed in your country, then you can use `iptables` and block all requests except from the IPv4 addresses allocated to your country. [Find your country's registrar here](https://www.iana.org/numbers).

If you want to protect your server, there is a few things you can do. First is use [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page). Set it up so that on certain attacks, it will automatically block the ip.  You should also use [ModSecurity](https://modsecurity.org/) for Apache's httpd.  If you have the power on the system, I suggest an IDS; I recommend [Suricata](http://suricata-ids.org/).

You could use a cronjob to grab the latest blacklist from the provider of your [choice](http://whatismyipaddress.com/blacklist-check) and create iptable rules for them...but that will slow down your connection a bit when you have a LOT of rules. (FYI, if you use an IDS, it will take care of the blacklists for you and will be faster).